# Laravel Event Broadcasting and Notification

Tags: laravel, events, notifications

I haven a Laravel app with a chat functionality which is working with an event called MessageSent. This event is broadcasted to a private channel, following the instructions of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#introduction).

This is working for my web listener, but now I need to send a notification to my FCM and APN channels.

What's a good approach to achieve this functionality? Do I have to create a notification or does this event class MessageSent works for broadcast on FCM and APN channels?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Queueing listeners` to your `Event` to handle sending FCM notifications, as you seen in [Events documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events):

> Queueing listeners can be beneficial if your listener is going to
> perform a slow task such as sending an email or making an HTTP request